# Immuitable recursive linear search of an array of string

Tags: algorithm, f#

I am new to F#. Is the following code, which represents about three hours of work, a canonical way to achieve its goals. If not, how can it be improved?

For instance, can we provide a default value of zero for the `index` parameter? Also, how do we handle a search for a term that does not exist? Could we use something similar to `tail::head` instead of matching against `array.[index]`? It looks more verbose that it needs to be.

```
open System

let rec linearSearch (array: string[]) (target: string) (index: int) = 
    match array.Length with 
    | l when index >= l -> -1
    | _ -> 
        match array.[index] with 
        | x when x = target -> index
        | y -> linearSearch array target (index + 1)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let names = [|
        "erdnase"
        "vernon"
        "le paul"
        "scarne"
        "ireland"
    |]
    linearSearch names "le paul" 0 |> printfn "The target is at index: %A" 
    linearSearch names "luttin" 0 |> printfn "The target is at index: %A" 
    0
```

The goals for writing the code were:

1. Use an array instead of a list, because I would like to understand F# arrays.
2. Implement a linear search, because it is a simple algorithm.
3. Write in canonical F#, because canonical code is more maintainable.

Comment: what is this code meant to do?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon return the index of an element if it exists, `-1` otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The additional argument `index` is error prone. For example, a user might provide `-1` and you end up with `array.[-1]`. So let us get rid of that first:

```
let linearSearch (array: string[]) (target: string) = 
    let rec search index = 
            match array.Length with 
                | l when index >= l -> -1
                | _ -> 
                    match array.[index] with 
                    | x when x = target -> index
                    | y -> search (index + 1)
    search 0
```

Now the recursive call is hidden in `search`, and also the `index` cannot get negative or otherwise mangled by a user. Next, we can make your `linearSearch` more general:

```
let linearSearch (array: 'a[]) (target: 'a) = 
    let rec search index = 
            match array.Length with 
                | l when index >= l -> -1
                | _ -> 
                    match array.[index] with 
                    | x when x = target -> index
                    | y -> search (index + 1)
    search 0
```

After all it should work for anything we can compare with `=`. Talking about comparing something, your pattern matches aren't really matching anything. You're just checking whether a condition has been met. Use usual structures instead:

```
let linearSearch (array: 'a[]) (target: 'a) = 
    let rec search index = 
            if index >= array.Length then
              -1
            elif target = array.[index] then
              index
            else
              search (index + 1)
    search 0
```

And last but not least, I would use the same promises as the usual C#/F# functions: either throw an exception when the value has not been found, or return an `Option`. That way, *if* we got an `int`, it's valid, so we don't have to check for an invalid position. I've [choosed `option`](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/the-option-type/):

```
let linearSearch (array: 'a[]) (target: 'a) = 
    let rec search index = 
            if index >= array.Length then
              None
            elif target = array.[index] then
              Some index
            else
              search (index + 1)
    search 0
```

But that's up to you.

## Exercise

1. Write a function `linearFind` that uses a function to find the correct index:

   ```
   linearFind (array : 'a[]) (predicate: a' -> bool) = …
   ```

   If `linearFind` returns `Some index`, then `predicate array.[index]` should be true.
2. Express `linearSearch` in terms of `linearFind`.

Comment: Wrapping the recursive call in a non-recursive call reminds me of the facade pattern from object-oriented programming.

Answer (score 2):

When your `match` expression has many `when` guards and no actual patterns, it's a sign that you're abusing it. Use `if`/`else` instead:

```
if array.Length <= index then 
  -1
elif array.[index] = x then 
  index
else
  linearSearch array target (index + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer reminds me of this: "The moral of the tale is: if you find yourself using if-then-else or matching on booleans, consider refactoring your code." https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/control-flow-expressions/